# Postgres query optimization on joins and where in clauses

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.1

So I am trying to make a backend to send users notification from time to time. Now in order to do that I need to procure some data from different postgres tables. I wrote this query but it is taking 12-14 seconds to get the data.

When run without where in clause I get the data in almost 700ms.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t."playerId") t."gzpId", t."pubCode", t."playerId" as token, t."provider",
       COALESCE(p."preferenceValue",'en') as lang,
       s."segmentId" 
FROM "userPlayerIdMap" t LEFT JOIN
     "userPreferences" p
     ON t."gzpId"  = p."gzpId" LEFT JOIN
     "segment" s
     ON t."gzpId" = s."gzpId" 
WHERE t."pubCode" IN ('hyrmas','ayqioa','rj49as99') and
      t."provider" IN ('FCM','ONE_SIGNAL') and
      s."segmentId" IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) and
      p."preferenceValue" IN ('en','hi') 
ORDER BY t."playerId"  desc;
```

Rows in "userPlayerIdMap" = 650000

Rows in "userPreferences" = 1456466

Rows in "segment" = 5674186

I have already added indexes on the required columns. 
Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: *". I wrote this query but it is taking 12-14 seconds to get the data."* Offtopic maybe?? But: PostgreSQL 9.1 ? Also about time to consider a upgrade then as PostgreSQL devs do not [support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) this version anymore meaning no more security or performance patches/updates..  Also the modern more versions tends to have much better optimisation to gain more performance..

Comment: "When run without where in clause"  You have 4 different where in clauses.  Are you leaving off all of them?  Please show the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of both forms of the query.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: without where in clauses the time is 600ms while with them it is 16 seconds. Looping through the array in where in clauses is very costly

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
SELECT t."gzpId", t."pubCode", t."playerId" as token, t."provider",
       COALESCE((SELECT p."preferenceValue"
                 FROM "userPreferences" p
                 WHERE t."gzpId" = p."gzpId" AND
                       p."preferenceValue" IN ('en', 'hi')
                 LIMIT 1
                ), 'en'
               ) as lang,
       (SELECT s."segmentId" 
        FROM "segment" s
        WHERE t."gzpId" = s."gzpId" AND
              s."segmentId" IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        LIMIT 1
       ) as segmentId
FROM "userPlayerIdMap"  
WHERE t."pubCode" IN ('hyrmas', 'ayqioa', 'rj49as99') and
      t."provider" IN ('FCM', 'ONE_SIGNAL')
-- ORDER BY t."playerId"  desc;
```

I'm not sure the `ORDER BY` is necessary.  If it was only being used for the `DISTINCT ON`, then it is not necessary in this version of the logic.

At the very least (with the `ORDER BY`) this will reduce the number of rows that need to be sorted.  If you don't need the `ORDER BY`, then there is no sort -- a significant performance gain.

Then, you want indexes on:

- `userPreferences(gzpId, preferenceValue)`
- `segment(gzpId, segmentId)`

The index on `userPlayerIdMap` is trickier.  I don't think that Postgres can use the index for both `in`s without a scan.  You want the more selective column first, but one of:

- `userPlayerIdMap(provider, pubCode, gzpId)`
- `userPlayerIdMap(pubCode, provider, gzpId)`

I threw `gzpId` so Postgres can use the index to look up the values in the subquery.

Comment: *"I'm not sure the ORDER BY is necessary. If it was only being used for the DISTINCT ON, then it is not necessary."* i have to disagree on that statement as `DISTINCT ON` syntax would require a deterministic sort (fixed) right, to prevent getting non deterministic (random) results from ever happening..  .. As `DISTINCT ON` syntax is simply syntax  sugar in PostgreSQL to solve *"first record(s) per group"* or *"last record(s) per group"* problems/questions more easy, in other SQL dialects this problem/question is *"harder"* to solve

Comment: @raymondnijland ... you misunderstood what I meant.  In rewriting the query, the order by is not necessary if it is only used in the original query for the distinct on.

Comment: *"you misunderstood what I meant"* No not really your statement was *"unclear/unlogical** defined a hour ago what you meant with that statement when i wrote that comment besides that other people seams to also agreeing on that comment which i made.... The way you wrote the statement its context pointed to the topicstarters SQL and not your rewritten version, that was mine main point about making mine comment..